# Defining different gnuplot environments

Tags: environment-variables, gnuplot, key-bindings

I have defined a few key bindings for gnuplot in a file `key-bindings.gp` which I can have available by launching gnuplot with
`gnuplot key-bindings.gp -`

However, if I do this, then gnuplot does not load the command history; it is just empty. (NB: I guess it makes sense in the way that specifying a script with gnuplot-commands on the command line is intended for batch processing rather than an interactive session.)

On the other hand, I also would not like to have these key bindings in my central `~/.gnuplot` file but I want to have them available only in certain situations.

Is there a way to load these key bindings on start-up, i.e. to define different gnuplot environments without losing access to my command history?

One way would be to do `load 'key-bindings.gp'` once I've started gnuplot but I don't like this because I want to automate some gnuplot processes and I also don't know how to automatically write this command onto the gnuplot command line...

Answer (score 0):

Using environmental variables

```
[1] cat ~/.gnuplotrc 
    env1 = system("echo $MY_KEYS")
    if (env1 ne "") load env1
    env2 = system("echo $MY_STYLES")
    if (env2 ne "") load env2

[2] setenv MY_KEYS key-bindings.gp
[3] setenv MY_STYLES pref-styles.gp
[4] gnuplot
gnuplot> print env1
key-bindings.gp
gnuplot> history !print
Executing:
    print env1
foo.gp
```

Comment: This is a bit more involved than I expected/hoped, but it is a solution. It's a shame gnuplot is a bit tricky in this respect. Thanks!